# How to make generic protocol not generic in Swift? So I can use it as parameter type

Tags: swift

```
protocol A : AnyObject {
    associatedtype T
}

protocol B : A where T == Int {

}

func a(b: B) {

}
```

I tried this. However I get this error again:
`Error:(19, 11) protocol 'B' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Comment: The compiler currently cannot do this. If a protocol has an associatedtype, all inheriting protocols also have an associatedtype, even if that associatedtype is fixed. This will likely be improved in the future, but it is not currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what go in `a(b:)` function but you can maybe make it generic as well.

```
func a<T: B>(b: T) {

}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The method written using a generic type is allowed to get an object conforming the protocol `B`